# Python asynchronous concurrency in asynchronous function

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

How can I change this code to run `on_some_event` with `g()` instead of  `f()`  ?

```
def f(data):
    pass
async def g(data):
    pass

async def on_some_event(data):
    for i in data:
        threads.append(threading.Thread(target=f, args=(i,)))
        threads[-1].start()
    for i in threads:
        i.join()
```

What should I use to execute async functions concurrently in async function ?

Answer (score 1):

To run an `async` function (coroutine) you have to call it using an Event Loop.

Event Loops:

> You can think of Event Loop as functions to run asynchronous tasks and
> callbacks, perform network IO operations, and run subprocesses.

for example, Event Loop example to run `async` Function to run a single async function:

```
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(on_some_event('hello'))
loop.close()
```